# Why intent-filter action not get recognized when pushing to priv-app?

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-automotive

I am working on a system app (`system/priv-app/`). When I add a new intent filter action to one of activity in `AndroidManifest` and push the new apk to priv-app and try to launch that activity with adb shell (also from thirt party app), I get `Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=com.example.SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 }`.
Tried reboot after pushing the app to priv-app.

Manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".ui.activity.AppSettingsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data android:name="distractionOptimized" android:value="true"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.SETTINGS"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Launch that activity with below adb command

```
adb shell am start -a com.example.SETTINGS
```

and from third party app

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.SETTINGS"));
```